# Split file into two tempfiles in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a large file with 2 different formats separated by a dashed line, how can I split the file into two tempfiles for processing?

Example:

```
yaml:format
yaml:format
yaml:format
---------
csv,format
csv,format
etc.
```

Comment: What is 'large'? Depending on your definition of large, the solution may be easier or harder...

Comment: The file size is actually variable, but almost everytime the dashed line is before line number 100

Comment: Ok good to know then you should be fine. I thought maybe large means megabytes of text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split at exactly twelve dashes:

```
yaml, csv = input.split('------------', 2)
```

or at a variable number of dashes

```
yaml, csv = input.split(/^-+$/, 2)
```

this will produce empty lines around the delimiter (end of `yaml` and start of `csv`), if you want to get rid of them you can do

```
yaml, csv = input.split(/[\r\n]+^-+$[\r\n]+/, 2)
```

Comment: when I try to puts the yaml, it prints the whole file, and csv var is empty.

Comment: I guess the delimiter can be of variable length? Edited my answer to reflect variable length delimiters.

Comment: is exactly 12 dashes. Always.

Comment: This is my code so far:

     `txt = open(url, :http_basic_authentication=>['user', 'pass'])` 
     `file = File.read(txt)`
     `delimiter = "------------"`
     `y, c = file.split(/#{delimiter}\n/, 2)`
     `puts y`

Comment: Works for me, double checked. Maybe the line endings? Edited.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't mind the empty lines in the string thats the simplest way :)